# css code how to change active navigation button color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my navigation buttons I have the following:-
**Home, Aboutus ,Profiles, More, Contact us**
What I need is suppose when I work on **home** its text color will change to **yellow**,others will remain the white color..when I click **aboutus** its text color will change to **yellow**,others will remain the white color.

so I have this:--

**style.css**

```
a.active{
    color: yellow;
} 

/* 
a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
} */



/* Toggled State */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(250px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(250px);
  -o-transform: translateX(250px);
  transform: translateX(250px);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}



  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .navigation.primary {
    max-width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: #393b3d;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px dotted #000;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }


  .navigation.primary a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }


  .navigation.primary ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #999;
  }



  .navigation.primary ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
  }

/*    .navigation.primary ul li a:active {
    color: yellow;
  } */
}
}
```

and html file is following:--

```
<body>

  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu">
<div class="wrapper">
<label for="toggle-menu">&gt;</label>
<h1>realNews</h1>
<div class="navigation primary">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div class="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuriesLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here,When I click any button its changing to yellow color.but not staying.I need to remain yellow color until I click another button.what I am doing wrong???
I have the **a:active{color:yellow}** so,why it is not staying?

Comment: is usage of jquery ok for you?

Comment: I havn't use jquery/javascript..But I Think I have to use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery its very simple to do

See the below demo

http://jsfiddle.net/pqckxw59/

Complete html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".clearfix li").live("click",function(){
    $(".clearfix li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
<style>
    .active{
        background-color:Yellow;
    }
body {
  background-color: #f0f6ff;
  font-family: arial, georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}


a:active {
  color: yellow;
     } 



p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
.wrapper .content {
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

label {
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(250px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(250px);
  -o-transform: translateX(250px);
  transform: translateX(250px);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.navigation.mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.navigation.mobile ul {
  width: 250px;
}
.navigation.mobile ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.navigation.mobile ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
.navigation.mobile ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #82b965;
  color: #333;
}

.navigation.primary {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  label {
    display: none;
  }

  .navigation.mobile {
    display: none;
  }

  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .navigation.primary {
    max-width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: #393b3d;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px dotted #000;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }


  .navigation.primary a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .navigation.primary ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #999;
  }



  .navigation.primary ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="toggle-menu">&gt;</label>
    <h1>rainBow</h1>
    <div class="navigation primary">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**If you need a pure css solution check the below link**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNxpqb

Comment: did you include jquery js in your html page?

Comment: i have added the complete html code, save it as .html and try

Comment: It is working..But only the background color is changing..I need to change the text color.

Comment: add this code to css .active a {
  color: red !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `a:active` for active link and for visited you can use `a:visisted`

**For iE**

```css
a:active{
 color:Yellow;  
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-menu">&gt;</label>
<h1>rainBow</h1>
<div class="navigation primary">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use class

html

```
<li><a href="#" class="active">About us</a></li>
```

js

```
var navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation ul li a');
for(var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++){
    navItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        for(var j = 0; j < navItems.length; j++)
            navItems[j].className = '';
        this.className = 'active';
    });

}
```

css

```
a.active{color:#ff0}
```

Comment: I can not understand..here,in the link it is working..but why it is not working in my file??

Comment: please post your file lemme check it

Answer (score 0):

What Ghost rider is asking about is not to just change the color while the link is being clicked, or for visited links (that won't reset when clicking another link).

I don't think there is any selector to accomplish what you're looking for on the fly with CSS. However, you could do something like this in jQuery/JS:

In your script:

```js
/*
 This will work specifically with your primary menu links,
 and won't alter any other div links. You also won't need
 to make changes to your CSS, but you could otherwise do
 the same with classes if you wish to toggle a CSS class.
 */
$('.navigation.primary > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  //reset all menu links to default color
  $('.navigation.primary > ul > li > a').css('color', '#fff');
  //set currently pressed to active color which will remain until next link pressed
  $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f6ff;
  font-family: arial, georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}


a:active {
  color: yellow;
     } 



p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #000;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
.wrapper .content {
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

label {
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(250px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(250px);
  -o-transform: translateX(250px);
  transform: translateX(250px);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.navigation.mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.navigation.mobile ul {
  width: 250px;
}
.navigation.mobile ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.navigation.mobile ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
.navigation.mobile ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #82b965;
  color: #333;
}

.navigation.primary {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  label {
    display: none;
  }

  .navigation.mobile {
    display: none;
  }

  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .navigation.primary {
    max-width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: #393b3d;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px dotted #000;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }


  .navigation.primary a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .navigation.primary ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #999;
  }



  .navigation.primary ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navigation.primary ul li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="toggle-menu">&gt;</label>
<h1>rainBow</h1>
<div class="navigation primary">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: Just in case please keep in mind this will only work while the user is on the same page and clicking anchor links, it will reset once they leave to another page/reload.

Comment: @Ghostrider have you check the links that i have posted

Comment: In this line :---$('.navigation.primary > ul > li > a').click(function() {
It is showing that:--
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: I can not understand..here,in the link it is working..but why it is not working in my file??

Comment: @Ghostrider i have added complete html code, check if its working

Comment: Yes ..I have dont this..I am updating the ques.then you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove active class and add class for current selection:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $('.clearfix a').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can does like this

```css
.navigation ul a.active{
    // write your color code here.
}

or

.navigation ul a:active{
    // write your color code here.
}
```

Comment: It is working only when I click..then changes the color.

Comment: @Ghost rider then just add a class with meaningful name on click event of that particular <a> tag of class navigation